# How to specify from which jar to read resource

Tags: java, classpath

Is it possible to specify from which jar resources are loaded when using:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file1.sql");
```

In more detail I am versioning jars with resource files using partly gradle and partly ivy (this is the state the project currently is and I cannot change this). This does work and I get both files-jar-1.0.0 and files-jar-1.0.1 inside my classpath. But how do I specify from which one of these two files I want to read the resource?

Answer (score 1):

You specify this by the order of the jars in the classpath.

Take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

Comment: Thank you for the info. I get that you  are referring to "Specification order
The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the directories in the order they appear in the class path variable." in that document but unfortunately that would require passing arguments to JVM when starting. I am looking for a way to do this in code with specifying some options on the class loader. If I find that that is not possible then this answer will probably be the approach I will take.